# Ubuntu 14.04 installed without repositories?

Tags: apt

I have installed Ubuntu 14 (LTS) and there is not a single debian package that I can install right out of the box.

for instance:

```
sudo apt-get install docker
```

results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker
```

What could be the problem?
On any other installation I have made of Ubuntu I could do stuff like that from the start with no additional configuration.

Comment: Start `sudo apt-get update` and try it again.

Comment: Great, answer done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker` is located in Ubuntu's `universe` repository. Open Software & Updates, check the box to enable the universe, and try again. Alternatively, you can edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add these four lines:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
```

`sudo apt-get update` and try it again.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple. You have never started `sudo apt-get update`. Do it now and add the universe repository, which isn't enabled per default, to install `docker`:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
```